# Problemas para Crear una AppPlatafom en Digital Ocean

Tags: reactjs

Estuve intentando subir mi app de React a la plataforma de AppPlatform de digital ocean pero he estado teniendo problemas para lograrlo, la verdad estuve utilizando googel firebase y no tive problemas , pero ahora con digital ocean no logro entender que tipo de problema esta teniendo para que se pueda general un build de la app

La verdad es mas que una pregunta es una consulta , les dejo una imagen de la consola de digital ocean para que puedan ver que problema esta mostrando

```
[2023-03-08 19:41:28] ╭──────────── git repo clone ───────────╼
[2023-03-08 19:41:28] │  › fetching app source code
[2023-03-08 19:41:28] │ => Selecting branch "main"
[2023-03-08 19:41:32] │ => Checking out commit "d6ae117e8463bfc9ad9a91fa07fac98286ba0f09"
[2023-03-08 19:41:32] │ 
[2023-03-08 19:41:32] │  ✔ cloned repo to /workspace
[2023-03-08 19:41:32] ╰────────────────────────────────────────╼
[2023-03-08 19:41:32] 
[2023-03-08 19:41:32]  › applying source directory frontend/vinculaciones-app
[2023-03-08 19:41:32]  ✔ using workspace root /workspace/frontend/vinculaciones-app
[2023-03-08 19:41:32] 
[2023-03-08 19:41:32]  › configuring custom build command to be run at the end of the build:
[2023-03-08 19:41:32]    │ npm run build
[2023-03-08 19:41:32] 
[2023-03-08 19:41:32] ╭──────────── buildpack detection ───────────╼
[2023-03-08 19:41:32] │  › using Ubuntu 18.04 stack
[2023-03-08 19:41:32] │ Detected the following buildpacks suitable to build your app:
[2023-03-08 19:41:32] │ 
[2023-03-08 19:41:32] │    heroku/nodejs-engine   v0.5.1  
[2023-03-08 19:41:32] │    digitalocean/node      v0.3.4  (Node.js)
[2023-03-08 19:41:32] │    digitalocean/procfile  v0.0.3  (Procfile)
[2023-03-08 19:41:32] │    digitalocean/custom    v0.1.1  (Custom Build Command)
[2023-03-08 19:41:32] │ 
[2023-03-08 19:41:32] │ For documentation on the buildpacks used to build your app, please see:
[2023-03-08 19:41:32] │ 
[2023-03-08 19:41:32] │    Node.js  v0.3.4  https://do.co/apps-buildpack-node
[2023-03-08 19:41:32] ╰─────────────────────────────────────────────╼
[2023-03-08 19:41:32] 
[2023-03-08 19:41:32] ╭──────────── app build ───────────╼
[2023-03-08 19:41:32] │ ---> Node.js Buildpack
[2023-03-08 19:41:32] │ ---> Installing toolbox
[2023-03-08 19:41:32] │ ---> - jq
[2023-03-08 19:41:33] │ ---> - yj
[2023-03-08 19:41:34] │ ---> Getting Node version
[2023-03-08 19:41:34] │ ---> Resolving Node version
[2023-03-08 19:41:35] │ ---> Downloading and extracting Node v16.19.1
[2023-03-08 19:41:38] │ ---> Parsing package.json
[2023-03-08 19:41:38] │ ---> No file to start server
[2023-03-08 19:41:38] │ ---> either use 'docker run' to start container or add index.js or server.js
[2023-03-08 19:41:39] │ Project contains package-lock.json, using npm
[2023-03-08 19:41:39] │ Found npm version range ">=9.6.0" in package.json->engines.npm
[2023-03-08 19:41:39] │ Installing npm ">=9.6.0"
[2023-03-08 19:41:43] │ 
[2023-03-08 19:41:43] │ added 1 package, and audited 237 packages in 3s
[2023-03-08 19:41:43] │ 
[2023-03-08 19:41:43] │ 16 packages are looking for funding
[2023-03-08 19:41:43] │   run `npm fund` for details
[2023-03-08 19:41:43] │ 
[2023-03-08 19:41:43] │ found 0 vulnerabilities
[2023-03-08 19:41:43] │ 
[2023-03-08 19:41:43] │ Installing node_modules using npm (from package-lock.json)
[2023-03-08 19:41:43] │ Running npm ci
[2023-03-08 19:41:43] │ 
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! code EUSAGE
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! 
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! 
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's ajv@6.12.6 does not satisfy ajv@8.12.0
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 does not satisfy json-schema-traverse@1.0.0
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! Missing: typescript@4.9.5 from lock file
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! Missing: ajv-keywords@3.5.2 from lock file
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! Missing: ajv-keywords@3.5.2 from lock file
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! Missing: ajv-keywords@3.5.2 from lock file
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! 
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! Clean install a project
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! 
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! Usage:
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! npm ci
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! 
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! Options:
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! [-S|--save|--no-save|--save-prod|--save-dev|--save-optional|--save-peer|--save-bundle]
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! [-E|--save-exact] [-g|--global]
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! [--install-strategy <hoisted|nested|shallow|linked>] [--legacy-bundling]
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! [--global-style] [--omit <dev|optional|peer> [--omit <dev|optional|peer> ...]]
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! [--strict-peer-deps] [--no-package-lock] [--foreground-scripts]
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! [--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit] [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! [-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! 
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! 
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ 
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ npm ERR!     /home/apps/.npm/_logs/2023-03-08T19_41_43_942Z-debug-0.log
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ 
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ unable to invoke layer creator
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ installing node_modules: exit status 1
[2023-03-08 19:41:45] │ ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
[2023-03-08 19:41:46] │ 
[2023-03-08 19:41:46] │ 
[2023-03-08 19:41:46] │ For documentation on the buildpacks used to build your app, please see:
[2023-03-08 19:41:46] │ 
[2023-03-08 19:41:46] │    Node.js  v0.3.4  https://do.co/apps-buildpack-node
[2023-03-08 19:41:46] │ 
[2023-03-08 19:41:46] │  ✘ build failed


-------------Package.Json File---------------------------
   {
  "name": "vinculaciones-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12.x.x <=16.x.x",
    "npm": ">=9.6.1"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emailjs/browser": "^3.10.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "apisauce": "^2.1.6",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.3",
    "core-js": "^3.29.0",
    "emailjs": "^4.0.1",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^4.2.1",
    "react-modal": "^3.16.1",
    "react-paginate": "^8.1.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.2",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.7.3",
    "web-vitals": "^3.1.1",
    "yup": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
     "build:digitalocean": "npm install --production=false && npm run build && npm ci"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.1",
    "gh-pages": "^5.0.0"
  }
}

------------------------------------------------------------

-------Package-lock.json File-------------------------------
{
  "name": "vinculaciones-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 3,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "vinculaciones-app",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "dependencies": {
        "@emailjs/browser": "^3.10.0",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
        "apisauce": "^2.1.6",
        "axios": "^1.3.4",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
        "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.3",
        "core-js": "^3.29.0",
        "emailjs": "^4.0.1",
        "formik": "^2.2.9",
        "leaflet": "^1.9.3",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.2",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
        "react-leaflet": "^4.2.1",
        "react-modal": "^3.16.1",
        "react-paginate": "^8.1.4",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.8.2",
        "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
        "sweetalert2": "^11.7.3",
        "web-vitals": "^3.1.1",
        "yup": "^1.0.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.1",
        "gh-pages": "^5.0.0"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=12.x.x <=16.x.x",
        "npm": ">=9.6.1"
      }
    },
```

Esta es mi configuracion del package.json , no sabria decirles si me esta faltando algo pero lo unico diferente que agregue es lo de la documentacion oficial de DigitalOcean

https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/reference/buildpacks/nodejs/

Comment: nodejs v0.3.4? npm ~1.0.2? Esas versiones son reeeviejas... quizas tienes alguna configuración rara en el `package.json`, podrías poner el contenido de ese archivo en tu pregunta? Recuerda que la puedes [edit]

Comment: acabo de plublicar la informacion de mi archivo package.json , esta tarde voy a estar probando a ver si lo puedo resolver por mi cuenta , pero voy a ver si alguien me puede dar una mano tambien por esta pregunta

Comment: he notado que ahora con mi package-lock.json el npm ci de digital ocean arroja el siguiente error ' npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing. '

Comment: intente borrar el package-lock.jason y agregar nuevamente un npm install pero sigue pasando lo mismo

Comment: SOLUCION : por si a alguien le sirve leer esto en algun momento y este travado como yo lo estaba , mi solucion para poder generar un deploy al Appplataform de DigitalOcean fue directamente cambiar el gestor de paqueres de NPM a Yarn , directamente en mi app de react

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71481424/16054427

Comment: Utilize ese post como ayuda , espero que a alguien le sirva : )